# Cast IFRAME into Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, iframe

is it possible if I get an IFRAME elemenet from my webBrowser and cast it into a bitmap? The IFRAME uses src attribute that points to a dynamic image.

Usually what I do when I want to do this with an IMG element, is I copy it to clipboard `IHTMLControlRange` and then cast it to bitmap from there.

This doesn't seem to work for IFRAME, anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use print screen functionality, mimicking an ALT-Print Screen action.  That will give you the window as a bitmap, which includes the iFrame, and then you'd need to zero in on the exact coordinates and crop the bitmap.

Here is another SO question that addresses the print screen functionality for C#:

[.NET 2.0 WinForm print screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008249/net-2-0-winform-print-screen)

Here is an article on cropping an image in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt4bf7h.aspx

EDIT: Changed the URL I originally posted for image cropping...that was more specific to WPF, sorry.